# How can I disable or hide context menu from a particular column of angular ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have angular ag-grid and needed to display the context menus in grid but do not want to show context menu in a particular column.

there is not any such property to hide from column.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `getContextMenuItems()` something like this -

```
getContextMenuItems(params) {

    if(params.column.colId == "columnToDisable") {
      return [];
    } else {
     // otherwise return array of context menu items
   }
}
```

More in the docs [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context-menu/#configuring-the-context-menu)